# Проблема с кириллицей при генерации PDF из SVG изображения при помощи класса PHP - TCPDF

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, php, svg

У меня стоит задача сгенерировать, с помощью PHP, PDF файл из изображения SVG. Сначала попробовал класс FPDF, но он не поддерживает генерацию PDF файла из изображения SVG, тогда обратился к другому классу TCPDF, он отлично генерирует PDF из изображений SVG, но возникла следующая проблема - все русские буквы в [изображении SVG](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/image.svg), при [генерации PDF](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/doc.pdf) отображаются вопросительными знаками. Как побороть данную проблему? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Как делать текстовые надписи на русском языке, при генерации PDF файла с помощью класса PHP - TCPDF, я разобрался. Но вот как исправить глюк с отображением русских символов, которые генерируются из SVG изображения не могу понять. Да и информации как исправить этот баг я так и не нашел. Подскажите, может кто-то уже сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос можно закрывать, я решил проблему.

```
$pdf->Output('doc.pdf', 'FI');
```

поменял на

```
$pdf->Output('doc.pdf', 'FD');
```

и стало все корректно отображаться, промучался долго, но достиг нужного результата. Возможно, кому-то пригодится мой опыт и мои мучения. ;)